# Software architecture/structure supporting different version of 3 party platform

Tags: visual-studio, architecture

I am currently writing software that is used in a third party software.

The third party software is used worldwide and different clients will be on different version of the software. For example, v1, v2, v3.

Currently, I have clients using v1, v2 and v3 so I need my code to work across different versions. I’m wondering how others have tackle this issue with managing your code, testing your code against different version etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

The general rule for this scenarios is to be driven by configuration not by if/else statements all across your code. Specific rules from v1, v2 and so one.

Also you need to have some handling for default applications.

## Driven by configuration and build time variables

Configuration in your case will be service container wiring file for dependency injection that have different implementations for your different clients - v1, v2.
With dependency injection you will have generic flow of your application and you can change underlying business logic by different implementation.

You can introduce different configurations variables so you can change on build time values.

## Common part

About common code you can use combination of decorator and command design pattern in order to have proper structure.

Also one additional pattern is nullable object if you want to turn off certain feature for client.

## Testing

About the testing - TDD and BDD based on your client requirements you will have all logic isolated in client specific.

## Naming

Naming should be done based on feature not client.

You can search more about building whitelable applications.